# Why it's so trouble when I want to insert some instructions in basicblock？

Tags: insert, llvm, llvm-ir

I found it so trouble when I try to insert some instruction in  basicblock.

```
AllocaInst* pa = new AllocaInst(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()), 0, 4, "dataKey");
Value* dataValue = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(),6) , 100);
```

above are some code I used. Still now I don't understand the principle to insert all kinds of instructions in basicblock.(I just can insert a allocaInst).  I  wish someone could tell me some example that inset all kinds of instructions in basicblock.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand after reading the relevant documentation? You have to be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the topic of inserting instructions is [covered in the LLVM Programmer's Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#creating-and-inserting-new-instructions), I recommend taking a look. The Programmer's Manual is a great place to start for beginners.

Additionally, there are tons of examples in the LLVM source code itself. For instance:

- [examples/Fibonacci/fibonacci.cpp](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/llvm/examples/Fibonacci/fibonacci.cpp?txt)
- [examples/ModuleMaker/ModuleMaker.cpp](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/llvm/examples/ModuleMaker/ModuleMaker.cpp?txt)
- Most [passes](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/dir_c8acc62e898517adbea11076b88ef3a0.html)

Alternatively, if you want to add multiple new instructions, consider using an [IRBuilder](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html), which makes it slightly more convenient to add them; [here's a tutorial on how to use an IRBuilder](http://llvm.org/releases/2.6/docs/tutorial/JITTutorial1.html).